# How to use the Pre trained models provided by Intel's OpenVINO

Tags: opencv, openvino

I am interested in a certain demo for OpenVino which is the smart classroom
link:https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo/tree/master/demos/smart_classroom_demo

But I only want the function of detecting raised hands hence I see that it provided the pre trained model here : https://download.01.org/opencv/2019/open_model_zoo/R1/20190404_140900_models_bin/person-detection-raisinghand-recognition-0001/FP16/

My Question is how can I utilize the pre trained models?

I have basic understanding of OpenCV for both in Python and C++ so if anyone could actually lead me to articles that explain steps by steps on how to use this model, it would be very helpful.

Comment: Please make your question more specific, complete with things you tried and problem you faced.

Answer (score 2):

The Intel® Distribution of OpenVINO™ toolkit (formerly Intel® CV SDK) contains optimized OpenCV and OpenVX libraries, deep learning code samples, and pretrained models to enhance computer vision development.

It’s validated on 100+ open source and custom models, and is available absolutely free.

Kindly refer the below links to get an idea on this.

https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo/blob/master/intel_models/person-detection-raisinghand-recognition-0001/description/person-detection-raisinghand-recognition-0001.md

https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_person_detection_action_recognition_0005_description_person_detection_action_recognition_0005.html

https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_MO_DG_Deep_Learning_Model_Optimizer_DevGuide.html

https://techdecoded.intel.io/essentials/optimize-deep-learning-inference-applications-using-openvino-toolkit/#gs.l98omp

[How to use OpenVINO pre-trained models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55345798/how-to-use-openvino-pre-trained-models)

Hope these will help you.